# Network Manager DNS Issues

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, dns, networkmanager

I'm on [Debian Jessie Linux](https://www.debian.org/) with [LXDE](http://lxde.org/). I'm getting some strange behaviors with my networking. I essentially want to disable IPv6, use custom [OpenNIC DNS](https://www.opennicproject.org/), and [network-manager-gnome](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/network-manager-gnome) for wifi management.

*LXDE* recommends [wicd-gtk](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/net/wicd-gtk), but wifi does not work with it. No wifi networks show up, and my laptop wifi light stays orange (off) and does not change to blue (on). I'm not sure if it is me or my laptop's network card, but I installed [firmware-realtek](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-realtek) and wifi works with *network-manager* so I think it is just a bug with *wicd*.

The problem with *network-manager* though is that it overwrites **/etc/resolv.conf** with IPv6 DNS, even though [IPv6 has already been disabled](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6) in **/etc/sysctl.conf**. I modified **/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf** with `supersede domain-name-servers opennicdns#1, opennicdns#2, etc.` and removed the `request domain-name, dhcp6.name-servers` stuff, so the IPv4-only *OpenNIC DNS* works fine with *wicd-gtk* but not *network-manager-gnome*. What do I need to do so that *network-manager* uses the IPv4-only *OpenNIC DNS*?

Let me know if I need to provide any more information, and I will be glad to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I don't know what is wrong with `network-manager`, but to solve this I installed [resolvconf](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/resolvconf). I removed all the other files in **/etc/resolvconf/run/interface**, and added the *OpenNIC DNS* to **/etc/resolvconf/run/interface/NetworkManager**. Ran `sudo resolvconf -u` afterwards, and double-checked it with [DNSLeakTest](https://dnsleaktest.com/). Everything seems to be working! Based off [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf/565895#565895).